# why is the following not a metric on $R^2$?

Tags: metric-spaces

why is the following not a metric on $R^2$?

All 3 conditions are getting satisfied

$d((x,y),(x^{'},y^{'}))=|x|+|y|+|x^{'}|+|y^{'}|$

after many attempts by two of my friends please find the problem here

$d((x,y),(x^{'},y^{'}))=|x|+|y|+|x^{'}|+|y^{'}|=0 \iff x=y=x^{'}=y^{'}=0  \iff (x,y)=(x^{'},y^{'})$

Comment: Your argument is wrong because the last $\iff$ should be just $\implies $

Answer (score 3):

Is the distance from a point to itself always equal to zero in this proposed metric?

Comment: the property is $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$

Comment: No, I think you're confusing metrics with norms. The axiom for metrics is $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y$, whereas the corresponding axiom for norms is $\|x\| = 0$ iff $x=0$. In a metric space the expression $x=0$ doesn't even have to make sense.

Comment: $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

Comment: what is the problem here

Comment: The problem here is that the property $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y$ doesn't hold for $d$ as defined in your question. For a specific example, see Aloizio Macedo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=(1,1)$

Then, $d(x,x)=4$.

Comment: the property is $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$

Comment: where is the contradiction

Comment: [The property is not that one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition).

Sometimes, $0$ doesn't even make sense